# How to make use of Dictionary to count multiple Average values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have 3 columns in a csv file. "Pclass", "Sex", "Age". Pclass has 3 categorical values: 1, 2 & 3. Sex has values 'male' & 'female' and Age has values from 0 to 75.
Now, I want to count six different average ages based on pclass and sex. so there will be like 6 average values.
**(1-male)
(2-male)
(3-male)
(1-female)
(2-female)
(3-female)**

I made the following program. but I'm wondering if one can use dictionary to do the same.. dict = {} keys will me m1,m2 and so on... and somehow replace the Key's values with average value.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
prediction_set = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

dataset.isnull().sum()
prediction_set.isnull().sum()
 
'''Dealing with Missing Age'''
# we are going to catogorise age by Pclass and Sex

m1 = m2 = m3 = f1 = f2 = f3 = 0
count_m1 = count_m2 = count_m3 = count_f1 = count_f2 = count_f3 = 0

for i in range(0,891):
    if np.isnull(dataset['Age'][i]
        continue
    if dataset['Pclass'][i]==1:
        if dataset['Sex'][i]=='male':
            m1 = m1 + dataset['Age'][i]
            count_m1 = count_m1 + 1
    if dataset['Pclass'][i]==2:
        if dataset['Sex'][i]=='male':
            m2 = m2 + dataset['Age'][i]
            count_m2 = count_m2 + 1                    
    if dataset['Pclass'][i]==3:
        if dataset['Sex'][i]=='male':
            m3 = m3 + dataset['Age'][i]
            count_m3 = count_m3 + 1
    if dataset['Pclass'][i]==1:
        if dataset['Sex'][i]=='female':
            f1 = f1 + dataset['Age'][i]
            count_f1 = count_f1 + 1
    if dataset['Pclass'][i]==2:
        if dataset['Sex'][i]=='female':
            f2 = f2 + dataset['Age'][i]
            count_f2 = count_f2 + 1
    if dataset['Pclass'][i]==3:
        if dataset['Sex'][i]=='female':
            f3 = f3 + dataset['Age'][i]
            count_f3 = count_f3 + 1

m1 = m1/count_m1
m2 = m2/count_m2
m3 = m3/count_m3
f1 = f1/count_f1
f2 = f2/count_f2
f3 = f3/count_f3

print('m1 = ', m1)
print('m2 = ', m2)
print('m3 = ', m3)
print('f1 = ', f1)
print('f2 = ', f2)
print('f3 = ', f3)
```

please tell me whats wrong in it.

Comment: can you provide `dataset.to_string()` and `prediction_set.to_string()` in the question?

Comment: problem was there was some null values in 'Age' columns so it was causing the issue. I rectified it with an additional 'if' statement. but now I'm wondering if you can use dictionary to do the same. Please advise. thanks

Comment: can you provide dataset.to_string() and prediction_set.to_string() in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get mean age by the 6 groups (3 pclass category x 2 sex category), could try using:

```
dataset.groupby(['Pclass', 'Sex'])['Age'].mean()
```

Hope I didn't misinterpret your question.

Comment: OMG... did you just reduced my 7500 lines of code into 1??? Who are you..lol.

Comment: anyway.. how do i get these 6 values out in a variable now? does it return something that I can assign to?

Comment: If we assign the output to a variable called means like this: means = dataset.groupby(['Pclass', 'Sex'])[['Age']].mean() (please note this one has double bracket around age). To access the mean score, could try either of these: 1) means.query("Pclass==1 & Sex=='female'").values or 2) means = means.to_dict()['age'] and then means[(1, 'female')]

Comment: I tried this but got an error... whats wrong with it and how can you make it compact?

for i in range(0,891):
    if pd.isnull(dataset['Age'][i]):
        if dataset['Pclass'][i]==1:
            if dataset['Sex'][i]=='male':
                dataset['Age'][i]=means.query("Pclass == 2 & Sex == 'male'").values       
        if dataset['Pclass'][i]==2:
            if dataset['Sex'][i]=='male':
                dataset['Age'][i]=means.query("Pclass == 2 & Sex == 'male'").values
 and so on...for each group of Pclass & Sex

Comment: for c in df['Pclass'].unique():
    for s in df['Sex'].unique():
        df.loc[(df['Pclass']==c) & (df['Sex']==s) & df['Age'].isna(), 'age'] = means.query("Pclass==@c & Sex==@s").values[0][0]

Comment: That went over my head..lol. I need a tutor for this..  How can I chat with you to discuss this if you don't mind.

Comment: moreover, where do I learn all these shortcuts.. One can definitely dig into documentation but that's like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Hey, just so you know that code didn't work.. although it executed without any error but the missing values are still missing.